# How to call a method which is inside another classes?

Tags: java, spring, rest, vector

I have this method shown below. How can I call this method some where?. Since there is a method inside another I am not clear whether I should call the outer method or the inner one.

like this,

```
sendConfirmationEmail(user);
```

or

like this,

```
prepare(mimeMessage);
```

In second case do I need to handle the exception as well. Since I am not very comfortable with Java I don't really get this.

I'm creating an spring web application. I want to call this from a Java controller. Please help.

```
public void sendConfirmationEmail(final User user) {
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            message.setTo("sanduni@vclhq.com");
            //message.setFrom("adbuylk@gmail.com");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("adbuylk@gmail.com"));
            Map model = new HashMap();
            model.put("user", user);
            String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                    velocityEngine, "com/dns/registration-confirmation.vm", model);
            message.setText(text, true);
        }
    };
    this.mailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring, If you want to call another class's method you can wire the class which are required and can call method of another class.

Answer (score 0):

First autowire the service in where you want to call the method, Then using the autowired object call the function

```
@Autowired
 private EmailService emailService;
```

...........

```
emailService.sendConfirmationEmail();

................
```

Answer (score -2):

you can copy this codes into your service impl,then you can call your method

Comment: this is in service impl. I want to know how to call the method?

Comment: you can make it static also， that you can call it directly

Comment: yeah how to do that

Comment: use  @Autowire  in your controller  (dependency injection)